# Back tightness problem in barbell self unrack benchpress

Tags: bench-press

I'm trying to follow the barbell self unrack which involves laying on the bench as normal, doing an upright row and then dragging the feetback into using your body as a lever to wedge out the bar. Picture:

> [image]
>
> [Refer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8l2hMp21poo)

This helps me get a lot of lower back tightness, but I have no upper back tightness. Could someone advice me how to achieve that when doing this manueveur? Thanks.